# Is my work for part c of this problem correct? (involves chebychev theorem, I think)

Tags: probability

[image]

For part c, I used chebychev's theorem: $P(\mu - t\sigma < X < \mu + t\sigma) \ge 1 - \frac1{t^2}$, where $t$ is the number of standard deviations from the mean $\mu$.

In part c, $1 - \frac1{t^2} = .98$, and hence $t = \sqrt{50}$

We set $38k = \mu + t\sigma = \mu + \sigma \cdot \sqrt{50} = (.75)(48k) + \sqrt{50}*\sqrt{48k \cdot 0.75 \cdot 0.25}$

Solving for $k$, I got $12.19$, but I rounded up to $13$ because $12$ would give a probability less than $.98 (.97908)$. Hence, my final answer was $k = 13$.

Comment: How did you do a) and b)? I assume they want you to do c) the same way. I think Chebyshev is much too crude an approximation here.

Comment: i used normal approx to binomial for a and b

Comment: what do you mean it's too "crude"? How else would u solve this problem?

Comment: I mean the Chebyshev approximation is generally only a crude upper bound (with very few assumptions) and not suitable for obtaining sharp bounds in situations where there's more information. I would use the normal approximation or do it exactly with the binomial. Actually, looking more closely at your solution, I can't see how the answer shakes out to 12.19, which is actually almost exactly what you would get from the normal approximation. Solving for $k$ in the equation you described I get $k = 50\cdot9/4=112.5$ (!!) Are you sure you didn't somehow just use the normal approximation?

Comment: Think about it: with Chebyshev, you're talking about going out $\sqrt{50} \approx 7$ standard deviations. For a normal, that is deep, deep in the tail, well beyond the 99th percentile you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Computationally, your answer is right. With $k=13$ you get the smaller integer such that the condition is satified. But, your calculation is wrong. Using your procedure, the answer is $k=112.5$, as **spaceisdarkgreen** said in the comments. And again, like spaceisdarkgreen said, Chebyshev is not the best way to go.

The best way to go is with normal approximation:

\begin{align}
P(34k\leq V_{48k}\leq38k)&=P\left(\dfrac{34k-36k}{3\sqrt{k}}\leq\dfrac{V_{48k}-36k}{3\sqrt{k}}\leq\dfrac{38k-36k}{3\sqrt{k}}\right)\\
&=P\left(\dfrac{-2\sqrt{k}}{3}<Z<\dfrac{2\sqrt{k}}{3}\right)\\
\end{align}
Where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Let $z=2\sqrt{k}/{3}$. Then you want that $$P(|Z|<z)\geq 0.98$$ which is equivalent to $$P(Z<-z)\leq 0.01$$ so $-z\leq -2.326348$, then $k\geq 12.17676$, wich is closer to 13.

Comment: The exact calculation gives a probability of $98.2\%$ for $k=12.$ (Perhaps using a continuity correction will improve things).

Comment: You are right! So the answer that I gave is wrong. Maybe is about the normal correction of 1/2.